# Was Harry Harrison aware that he was giving James DiGriz a cover name that means "life vest"?

Tags: names, harry-harrison, the-stainless-steel-rat

In Harry Harrison's followup novel *[The Stainless Steel Rat's Revenge](https://books.google.com/books?id=UsaseaDUS_YC)*, criminal-turned-superspy James Bolivar DiGriz, also known as "The Stainless Steel Rat", infiltrates Cliaand, a grim world with an even grimmer society that I suppose is a parody of the Soviet Union.

When he arrives at the spaceport, we discover that he has been given a cover as an armaments salesman named "Pas Ratunkowy".

For years, I thought this was Polish for "Stainless Steel Rat", until I learned the truth in a very embarrassing way: on a Lot flight to Warsaw, I saw the words "pas ratunkowy" labeled right there of the back of the seat.

"Pas Ratunkowy" actually means "life vest"!

I half imagined the name to be something the ever-resourceful-but-facetious DiGriz could have made up on the spot. Now I wonder what Harry Harrison  was thinking at the time. Was there a reason for this particular name, other than its containing the letters R-A-T in sequence?

Comment: This may very well require Word of God to resolve, but it is an interesting notion.

Comment: Some of the SF writers I've known kept a notebook and jotted down things that might come in useful later. Harrison (whom I did not know) may well have flown on LOT and jotted down the words as something that seems alien to an English-speaker and sounds neat. (Coming up with names that 'feel' real is very hard.)

Comment: It seems unlikely to be a coincidence.  It's possible that Harrison didn't know what the words meant, but I can't imagine he just happened to create an alias that matched an existing Polish phrase.

Comment: @dmckee: Unfortunately, since Harrison passed away a year or so ago, it make take an actual Word of God...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots There may be a magazine interview somewhere, but I don't have access to that kind of stuff...

Comment: You are not the first to notice: https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalowy_Szczur#Ciekawostka - however, this appears to be conjecture, not verified.

Comment: @MarkOlson About your "jot things down in a notebook for later use" comment -- I am reminded that I once read a piece by Larry Niven in which he said that some of the "alien words" he invented for his Known Space stories had begun their existence as pesky typographical errors which he kept making when trying to type some other word or phrase. His advice was: *"Use your typoes!"*

Comment: @NeilSlater Perhaps the translator is still alive...

Comment: @NeilSlater [nope](https://pl.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarosław_Kotarski)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Harry Harrison loved to do language puns. He spoke several languages besides English, including Esperanto (of which he was a language ambassador), Danish, and likely Spanish, since he lived in Mexico for a while (IIRC).

Being Danish myself, I recognized several Danish puns, including the planet Skraldespand (Danish for garbage bin) and the strongest drink in the Universe, called Ladevandet (polite Danish for peeing).

I hence think it is fairly certain that the life vest pun is quite intentional.

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked the check mark back then.